# How to update rows using loops?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that creates a loop in a row until the specific cell value reaches 0.
And as you can see, if the value of that row is < than toremove, toremove becomes the differece between itself and the value of the row.

What I need to do is to set the value of that row to 0 and then, subtract the difference between toremove and that row, from the next row.

I'm super rusty in VB and VBA so I'm kinda lost. If anyone could help me or point me in the right direction, it'd be appreciated.

```
Set ws = Sheets("Carbonação")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("STOCK Membranas")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("STOCK Sticks")
        LR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        CR = ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        PR = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        CR2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        toremove = TextBox28.Text

        ws.Range("A" & LR).Value = Int((99999999 - 10000000 + 1) * Rnd + 10000000) 'ID Carbonação
        ws.Range("B" & LR).Value = ComboBox1.Text 'Fabricante
        ws.Range("C" & LR).Value = TextBox25.Text 'Lote Membranas
        ws.Range("D" & LR).Value = ws3.Range("A" & CR) 'ID Sticks
        ws.Range("E" & LR).Value = TextBox2.Text 'Nº Carbonação
        ws.Range("F" & LR).Value = TextBox3.Text 'Densidade Total / Carbonação
        ws.Range("G" & LR).Value = TextBox1.Text 'TETRA
        ws.Range("H" & LR).Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm") 'Data / Hora introdução

        Do While toremove > 0
            If ws2.Range("H" & PR).Value < toremove Then
                toremove = toremove - ws2.Range("H" & PR).Value
                ws2.Range("H" & PR).Value = 0
                ws2.Range("H" & PR) = ws2.Range("H" & PR) + 1
            Else
                ws2.Range("H" & PR).Value = ws2.Range("H" & PR).Value - toremove
                toremove = 0
            End If
        Loop
```

Comment: what is PR  value

Comment: Not sure the logic you are dealing, but shouldn't PR be changed?

Comment: In addition, if you need the next row, it should be `ws2.Range("H" & PR + 1)`

Comment: @Ashok `PR = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1`

Comment: @newacc2240 I already have a variable for the next row. But I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong, since I can't move on to the next row and subtract the difference there.

Comment: What is your variable for the next row? The line `ws2.Range("H" & PR) = ws2.Range("H" & PR) + 1` indicates value = value + 1

Comment: @newacc2240 my variable for the next row is `CR2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: How can your VBA execute that line since it is at the beginning of your code? You need to change you row **IN** your while loop if needed. Such as `PR = PR + 1` or something like that.

Comment: @newacc2240 Like [this?](https://pastebin.com/3CCbhRc7)

Comment: @newacc2240 alright. I did as you suggested and changed the row inside the loop, like in the link in the comment above. However, instead of subtracting the difference in the next row, starts by subtracting 3 and then 10. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. I still don't understand the goal that you wanted. State the ideal procedure step by step, and adding an example would be better. 2.I suggest you to trace the executation line by line by pressing F8. So you know how it works.

Comment: @newacc2240 I'm going to try my best to state the ideal procedure. I get a delivery for 100 soda bottles on 11/10/2017 and another delivery of 200 soda bottles on 25/10/2017. Let's say that I sell about 3 soda bottles everyday and every time I sell a bottle, the soda bottle inventory subtracts 3 bottles from the delivery made on 11/10/2017. On 31/10/2017 I sell 10 bottles and since my stock can't be negative, I need to sell the last ones from 11/10/2017 (I had 4 from that delivery) and sell 6 from the 25/10/2017. Was it clear enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Original version

I only look in to the while loop. Just take a look at these two lines.

```
 ws2.Range("H" & PR).Value = 0                   `1st
 ws2.Range("H" & PR) = ws2.Range("H" & PR) + 1   '2nd
```

When you calling a `Range Object`, the default property is `.Value`. Therefore, the 2nd line is the same as `ws2.Range("H" & PR).Value = ws2.Range("H" & PR).Value + 1`. Apparently, this is not what you want.

The only thing you have to correct is changing the 2nd line above. This is the edited version of the while loop.

### Edited version

```
Do While toremove > 0
    If ws2.Range("H" & PR).Value < toremove Then
        toremove = toremove - ws2.Range("H" & PR).Value
        ws2.Range("H" & PR).Value = 0
        PR = PR + 1
    Else
        ws2.Range("H" & PR).Value = ws2.Range("H" & PR).Value - toremove
        toremove = 0
    End If
Loop
```

The first time it goes into the while loop, assuming `PR = 10` and it goes into the true part of the if statement, so it checks range H10. When it leaves the if statement, PR is 11 now since we add 1 in PR. So next time it starts the while loop, it checks range H11 instead of H10.

Comment: Dude. That worked! Thank you so much! You saved me a lot of work and a headache.